# How to set window and it's graphicScene transparent(using slider) and leave only QPushButton visible

Tags: python, pyside2

I want my window and it's QGraphicsScene to be transparent which is controlled by QSlider.

I tried looking for some answers here and there, but it's mainly setting background color to 0 :

```
self.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);")
```

or like that :

```
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint) 
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

Which does it job, but I would like to make slider which will control level of transparency and I don't see how can I do it with commands above.

Can somebody please give me some advise how to do it ? Thank you

I will attach my test code here below(I want to be able to control transparency of everything , but do not touch slider and button):

```
from PySide2.QtGui import QBrush, QColor
from PySide2.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QFrame, QSizePolicy, QApplication, QSlider, QPushButton

class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.graphicsWidget = MainGraphicsWidget()
        self.window = 'transp_test'
        self.title = 'transparent UI'
        self.size = (1000, 650)
        self.create()


    def create(self, **kwargs):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.resize(QSize(*self.size))
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsWidget)


class MainGraphicsWidget(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainGraphicsWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(backgroundBrush = Qt.gray)
        self.setScene(self._scene)

        self.transpSlider = QSlider()
        self.transpSlider.setRange(0,100)

        self.mainButton = QPushButton('I want it to be "Test" button')

        self._scene.addWidget(self.mainButton)
        self._scene.addWidget(self.transpSlider)
        self.transpSlider.move(300, 100)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setGeometry(600, 300, 600, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        # these two lines are needed to get a transparent background in windows
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        # rest of class definition unchanged


class MainGraphicsWidget(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainGraphicsWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        # set transparent background color for the widget itself
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #00000000")
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(self._scene)

        # create of slider and connect to slot for changing opacity.
        self.transpSlider = QSlider()
        self.transpSlider.setStyleSheet('background-color: #00000000')
        self.transpSlider.setRange(0,255)
        self.transpSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.set_opacity)
        self.transpSlider.setValue(255)

        # rest of __init__ unchanged

    def set_opacity(self, value):
        brush = self.backgroundBrush()
        color = brush.color()
        color.setAlpha(value)
        brush.setColor(color)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(color)
```

Note that I've changed the range of the slider to 0-255 to make changing the opacity from fully opaque to fully transparent easier.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply , it works :) Sorry for delayed answer , had some troubles with PC.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
#from PySide2.QtGui import QBrush, QColor
#from PySide2.QtCore import QSize, Qt
#from PySide2.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QFrame, QSizePolicy, QApplication, QSlider, QPushButton

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, 
                             QFrame, QSizePolicy, QApplication, QSlider, QPushButton)


class MainGraphicsWidget(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainGraphicsWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self._scene = QGraphicsScene() 
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.transpSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(
            QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
            minimum=10,
            maximum=100,
            value=100,
            valueChanged=self.onValueChanged,
        )
        self.mainButton = QPushButton('I want it to be "Test" button \n QUIT')
        self.mainButton.resize(150, 150)
        self.mainButton.clicked.connect(parent.close)

        self._scene.addWidget(self.mainButton)
        self._scene.addWidget(self.transpSlider)
        self.transpSlider.move(300, 100)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        c = QColor(220, 30, 30)
        c.setAlphaF(1) 
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(c))
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onValueChanged(self, value):
        c = QColor(220, 30, 30)
        c.setAlphaF(value * 0.01) 
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(c))
        window.setWindowOpacity(value * 0.03)   
        self.setStyleSheet("MainGraphicsWidget {{background-color: rgba(0, 215, 55, {});}}".format(value))  


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, False)      
        self.setStyleSheet("MainWindow {background-color: rgba(0, 215, 55, 70);}")   

        self.graphicsWidget = MainGraphicsWidget(self)  

        self.window = 'transp_test'
        self.title  = 'transparent UI'
        self.size   = (1000, 650)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.resize(QSize(*self.size))

        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)       
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsWidget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 600, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply , it works also just fine. Sorry , I had troubles with PC so I couldn't get my hands on this matter and I marked answer which was first. Sorry for troubles